# Javascript /Typescript/Angular Hide a div based on time created

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a dynamic table data rows in Angular 7, I want to hide a record if it is created 6 months ago. I tried like this, rite now it is hiding all the records IRRESPECTIVE OF TIME CREATED, can any one correct the ngIf condition and type script code please so that it will hide only records which are created 6 months ago

HTML

```
<div class="request"  *ngIf="request.duration > six_month_before_date">
```

Typescript

```
 public date = new Date() ;
 public six_month_before_date= this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() -6); 

 private getRequestDuration(request) {
    console.log(request);
    let createdDate = new Date(request.createTime);
    let timeInMilliSeconds = this.currentDate.getTime() - createdDate.getTime();
    let seconds = timeInMilliSeconds / 1000;
    let minutes = seconds / 60;
    let hours = minutes / 60 + 5; // FIXME: EST Offset
    hours = hours > 0 ? hours : 0; // FIXME: Hack to address time-stamp conversions / daylight savings time
    let days = hours / 24;
    return (days > 0 ? Math.floor(days) + ' days, ' : '') + Math.floor(hours % 24) + ' hours';
  }

Request Object:
Object
agingCurrent: 121777671
agingTotal: 121902671
createTime: "2020-09-14T06:49:20"
createdBySso: "503184132"
duration: "1 days, 20 hours"
indErrored: false
indSavedToMdm: "TRUE"
indSubscribed: "TRUE"
partyId: "160598"
requestId: 627723
requestType: "Internal subscribe"
riskCategory: "ONE"
riskLevel: "MODERATE"
state: {status: "Active", label: "-"}
status: "APPROVED"
statusUpdateTime: "2020-09-14T06:51:25"
supplierId: "S18961"
supplierName: "LM Wind Power (Spain) SA"
transactionId: null
type: "SUBSCRIBE_INTERNAL"
updateTime: "2020-09-14T06:51:25"
version: 15
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: you're comparing a string in `duration` to a date object, that will never work

Comment: Hi bryan can you provide a solution ya duration is based to hide the supplier records 6 months ago can you provide me ngIf condition

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to do some debugging on:

`*ngIf="request.createTime > six_month_before_date">`

The easiest way I go about `Debugging` this would bo to replace this with something like:

`*ngIf="foo(request.createTime)`

and in your ts create a function:

```
    foo(requestCreatedTime) {
      console.log(this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() -6));
      console.log(requestCreatedTime);
      return (this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() -6); 
    }
```

This let's you see the values being used in the ngIf to figure out if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Updated the question please check

Answer (score 0):

right now you seem to be comparing a string to a date object, which can't work. Javascript has no way of comparing these things.

you need to convert the date string into an actual date object, and preferably a timestamp, to do a comparison:

```
// add a timestamp of the created date to the request
request.createTimeStamp = new Date(request.createTime).getTime();
```

then

```
// get the timestamp of 6 months prior
public six_month_before_date= this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() -6).getTime();
```

then hide the record if the created time stamp is less than the 6 months ago timestamp

```
<div class="request"  *ngIf="request.createTimeStamp < six_month_before_date">
```

Comment: actually i need to hide them based on duration if the duration of supplier is 180 days and above i want to hide that record

Comment: duration: "180 days, 20 hours" this is the object

Comment: you can't use that string to do anything useful other than display it to a user. you need an actual number or date to run a comparison. you could set some property like `request.durationDays` to `180.8333` and then run `*ngIf="request.durationDays > 180"`  but you can't use a string. javascript can't interpret the comparison. no programming language could without a specific function or library to do so.

Comment: you already have the solution. in the `getRequestDuration` function, underneath `let days = hours / 24` put `request.durationDays = days`, then change the ngIf to what I just put: `*ngIf="request.durationDays > 180"`

Comment: Hi bryan is it request.durationDays > 180?   , i want to hide the records which are created  180 days ago

Comment: and display records which are created less than 180 days ago